# Sudo apt-get update is not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, apt

I'm trying to update my Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspian via the terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

However, this delivers the following message:

```
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/lib/apt/methods/http: error while loading shared libraries: libnettle.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http returned an error code (127)
E: Method /usr/lib/apt/methods/http did not start correctly
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've been searching all over the web, but can't find the answer.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is not very good.  Is everything else working ok?  Paste in the output from `ldconfig -p | grep nettle` (if there's nothing, just say so).

Comment: can you reach the repository using a web browser? ... http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/buster/InRelease

Answer (score 2):

You can manually install the missing library (`libnettle`) by downloading it manually and installing with

```
wget http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/n/nettle/libnettle6_3.4.1-1_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnettle6_3.4.1-1_armhf.deb
```

It's hard to say how much damage your system has. If there's a couple of files missing, you can repair it manually, but if you somehow removed half of `/usr/lib`, it will take less time to simply reinstall.